# How to search local files with OpenSearchServer

Tags: server, search-engine, opensearch

I have created an new index with "file crawler" as template. I can see that it has crawled the files from the local folder. But how do i use this search? Is there any feature that can search and list one of my files?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you have tried. Explain why it did not work for you and what the expected results are.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.opensearchserver.com/documentation/tutorials/functionalities.md). They describe the main concepts available in OpenSearchServer. The chapter you will be interested in is **search-page-rendering**.

Comment: Not a tutorial, but a list of features.